# Trusted Site displaying as Unknown Zone (Mixed)

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-security

We have an application that must run in IE and the client insists the application runs as a Trusted Site.

When we set the url as a trusted site in IE settings the login page loads fine and IE says it's a trusted site but after logging in IE says it's now an Unknown Zone (Mixed).

I was expecting that there was a request to another domain but I've run fiddler and all requests go to the same domain.

Has anyone seen this before and know what the cause is or know what other investigation I could do?

Answer (score 0):

One other reason that I think contributes to this mixed zone for a site, is having both HTTPS **and** HTTP connections for downloading the site content.